# unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /path: no such file or directory

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile

I'm running

```
docker build 'path' -t dockercgi:v1
```

As output I'm getting:

> unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /root/Desktop/pythoncgiwithdockaer/Dockerfile: no such file or directory

How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you using symlink files in the directory? If so this won't work. Docker doesn't support soft links for the build context

Comment: Actually f was capital in docker file