# unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat <path> no such file or directory

Tags: linux, bash, docker, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to run [tacotron2](https://github.com/Rayhane-mamah/Tacotron-2) on `docker` within `Ubuntu WSL2 (v.20.04)` on `Win10 2004` build. Docker is installed and running and I can run `hello world` successfully.

(There's a [nearly identical question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46386805/unable-to-prepare-context-unable-to-evaluate-symlinks-in-dockerfile-path-lstat), but nobody has answered it.)

When I try to run `docker build -t tacotron-2_image docker/` I get the error:

`unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /home/nate/docker/Dockerfile: no such file or directory`

So then I navigated in bash to where docker is installed (`/var/lib/docker`) and tried to run it there, and got the same error. In both cases I created a `docker` directory, but kept getting that error in all cases.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: What do you get if you do `ls -l /home/nate/docker/Dockerfile` ?

Comment: `ls: cannot access '/home/nate/docker/Dockerfile': No such file or directory`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57724377/6309), the error might have nothing to do with "symlinks", and everything with the lack of `Dockerfile`, which should be in the [`Tacotron-2/docker`](https://github.com/Rayhane-mamah/Tacotron-2/tree/master/docker) folder.

[`docker build`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) does mention:

> The docker build command builds Docker images from a Dockerfile and a “context”.
> A build’s context is the set of files located in the specified `PATH` or URL.

In your case, `docker build -t tacotron-2_image docker/` is supposed to be executed in the path you have cloned the [`Rayhane-mamah/Tacotron-2`](https://github.com/Rayhane-mamah/Tacotron-2) repository.

To be sure, you could specify said `Dockerfile`, but that should *not* be needed:

```
docker build -t tacotron-2_image -f docker/Dockerfile docker/
```

Or:

```
cd
git clone https://github.com/Rayhane-mamah/Tacotron-2
cd Tacotron-2
cd docker
docker build -t tacotron-2_image .
```

> I thought these commands I'm executing are for the purpose of installing it

To build the image, you need the sources (the repository to clone).

Comment: VonC: I executed your first example and got `unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /home/nate/docker/Dockerfile: no such file or directory`. As for your 2nd example, how can I find where Tacotron is, and why would it be anywhere, since I thought it hasn't been installed yet.  I thought these commands I'm executing are for the purpose of installing it. ??

Comment: @HerrimanCoder Everything depends on a step I did not originally mention in the answer (now edited): you cloning the Tacotron-2 repository.

Comment: Thanks VonC. You got me further down the road. I have posted a follow-up question to get me the rest of the way, I hope you will take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63440113/how-to-install-and-run-tacotron2-on-ubuntu-wsl

Answer (score 2):

If the name of you `Dockerfile` is with capital `F` rename it

Answer (score 0):

For others like me who somehow couldn't get it works because of symlink

> just copy out your files out to a new directory that hasn't been symlink and build your image from there

if ony if you've confirm that your Dockerfile isn't dockerfile .Dockerfile ,DockerFile or dockerfile.txt .

My OS elementary which is base on ubuntu.