# How to install and run Tacotron2 on Ubuntu WSL?

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL Windows 10 Pro 2004 (19041.388), and I am very much wanting to run [Tacotron2](https://github.com/Rayhane-mamah/Tacotron-2) and try out the functionality. I have installed Tacotron2 from git via command-line, but I'm uncertain whether it built successfully. I am a beginner with Linux and Docker, and the install instructions from above-linked Tacotron2 seems confusing.

So here is where I am at:

1. Installed Docker, confirmed up and running, all good.
2. Downloaded [Tacotron2](https://github.com/Rayhane-mamah/Tacotron-2.git) via git cmd-line - success.
3. Executed this command: `sudo docker build -t tacotron-2_image -f docker/Dockerfile docker/` - a lot of stuff happened that seemed successful, but at the end, there was an error:

`Package libav-tools is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source However the following packages replace it:`

`ffmpeg`

`E: Package 'libav-tools' has no installation candidate The command '/bin/bash -c apt-get install -y libasound-dev portaudio19-dev libportaudio2 libportaudiocpp0 ffmpeg libav-tools wget git vim'`

`returned a non-zero code: 100`

At this point I am stuck. It's true that I'm looking to get unstuck on this error, but comprehensively I'm looking for exact steps to be able to run Tacotron2 and ultimately be able to feed it an mp3 file with someone's voice, and then be able to feed it some text, which it will then "speak" in that voice.

That is my understanding of what Tacotron2 is, but I am keen to know if I am going down the wrong path.

Comment: Did you try installing `ffmpeg`? (there may also be an `ffmpeg-delev` (or similar) that may help too). Otherwise, I'm out of ideas, hmm, execpt finding a `tacotron2` specific user/developer forum, possibly attached to its developers website? Good luck!

Comment: `sudo docker build`? Ideally, your user is part of the docker group and does not need sudo.

Comment: shellter, I installed ffmpeg (not sure if it was already installed), then reran `sudo docker build -t tacotron-2_image -f docker/Dockerfile docker/` - and got the same exact error, but much earlier. I found another post that said: "modify the Dockerfile and replace libav-tools with ffmpeg" - I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: VonC: not sure what you mean. Docker is already installed and running. I can run `Hello World` docker image successfully.

Comment: Sorry `ffmpeg` didn't solve your problem. I see a typo above, maybe `fmpeg-devel` or similar is needed? Sometimes install systems miss such obvious problems. Again, I'd be looking at the developer website. If you find others are having this problem there may be a solution that hasn't trickled down to S.O. yet. Good luck.

Comment: you need to provide your dockerfile

Answer (score 2):

Your issue looks quite similar to https://github.com/Rayhane-mamah/Tacotron-2/issues/475

The issue happens because you have `libav-tools` installation directives in your Dockerfile which is no longer has installation candidates.

To eliminate the error you need to open `docker/Dockerfile` in any text editor and remove `libav-tools` from the line that contains

```
apt-get install -y libasound-dev portaudio19-dev libportaudio2 libportaudiocpp0 ffmpeg libav-tools wget git vim
```

to have something like

```
apt-get install -y libasound-dev portaudio19-dev libportaudio2 libportaudiocpp0 ffmpeg wget git vim
```

Since package `ffmpeg` already in this list you don't need to add it again.

You can also remove `libav-tools` from the Dockerfile using sed command in the WSL shell (might need to add `sudo` before sed if you have error with permissions):

```
sed -i docker/Dockerfile -e 's/libav-tools\ //g'
```

Then your build command should pass.

Comment: wisp, that worked, thank you very much. Do you have any other advice related to my comprehensive question: `I would greatly appreciate a set of steps suitable for noobs that can be followed with precision to run Tacotron2` - and be able to train a custom voice to do TTS.

Comment: @HerrimanCoder the repo you provided in the question looks a bit out of date (no new commits for about 2 years). Maybe you want to check out this one: https://github.com/NVIDIA/tacotron2? 
If you believe that the first repo is still relevant you can try to do it without docker (if you can install python3, all libraries and packages to your WSL system - then you don't have to use docker after all).